# StaleElementReferenceException while waiting

Tags: c#, exception, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I have `wait` in my tests like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dr, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

...

wait.Until((d) =>
{
   if (d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@src='/loader.gif']")).Displayed)
   {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
       return false;
   }
   else
   {
       return true;
   }
});
```

I sometimes get `StaleElementReferenceException`. It works 95% of time and its failing on different places in test.

Error:

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : Element not
>   found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked
>   up

Comment: Is `d` a WebElement or a WebDriver? If the former one, ensure that it does not change while performing the wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try using ExpectedConditions and see if that helps.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
IWebElement loaderGif = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@src='/loader.gif']")));
```

Comment: Thanks! Had no problem since i used this.